# Error al utilizar forEach en un objeto

Tags: javascript, nodejs

tengo un pequeño sistema crud con nodejs, declare un objeto, que guardo unas tareas dentro de el, el problema es cuando quiero recorrerlo, con un foreach, me muestra un error _listado.forEach() is not a function

```
    const listado = [];
const _listado = {};

    listadoCompleto (){
        this._listado.forEach(tarea=>{
            console.log(tarea)
        })
/*         listado.forEach((tarea,id) => {
            console.log('id',id)  
        }) */
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que **[forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)** trabaja en base a arreglos, y como bien dices, tu quieres iterar un objeto.

Para ello, utiliza **[for in](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in)**

```
for (let i in data) {
   console.log(`valor => ${data[i]}`)
}
```

El cual te sirve para iterar sobre las propiedades de un objeto.

Acá un ejemplo más práctico

```js
const personaje = { id: 1, name: 'Gokú', type: 'Warrior' }

const items = () => {
   for (let i in personaje) {
      console.log(`Props =: ${personaje[i]}`)
   }
}

items()
```

Nos comentas si te sirvió.